# My Vagrant box forgets about the modifications I've done via vagrant ssh…

Tags: nginx, ssh, vagrant

I have a Vagrant box that works fine after `vagrant up`, however there was a small bug in the configuration within the box for one of the sites.

I had to `ssh` into the box and edit a file. Which I did:

1) I `vssh`'ed (this is my alias) to the box

2) I opened a file:

`sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/foo.bar.local.conf`

3) I pressed `i` to start editing specific part of the file

4) I pressed `ESC` to finish editing

5) I typed `:wq` to save my changes and exit `vim`.

6) I restarted `nginx` to see my changes.

`sudo service nginx restart`

Everything worked well but after a day or two (when I had to `vagrant halt && vagrant up`) the original issue reappeared. Then I realised I've forgotten about booting VM with `--provision` so it will read the change I made.

Apparently calling `vagrant up --provision` didn't work. I had to edit the `conf` file again. What am I missing to permanently store my changes?

Comment: Your services may be modifying that file upon restart.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, as if you have a script in your Vagrant configuration that is copying locally stored config files to the sites-enabled directory on the VM. If that's the case then edit those files instead.

--provision will not help in this case. --provision simply runs the provision code in Vagrantfile.